# Upgrade to 18.04: "failed to fetch" 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

I am trying to upgrade ubuntu from the 16.04 version to the 18.04 and I get he following error:

```
Could not download the upgrades 

    The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or 
    installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have 
    been kept. 

    Failed to fetch 
    http://ftp.stw-bonn.de/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libsub-quote-perl/libsub-quote-perl_2.005000-1_all.deb 
    403 Forbidden [IP: 212.201.68.60 80]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply worked by changing the donwload server from the Synaptic Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such folder as libsub-quote-perl in libs. You can check it http://ftp.stw-bonn.de/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/.
Instead, you can use this link: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main//libs/libsub-quote-perl/libsub-quote-perl_2.005000-1_all.deb if you want setup this package.

If you just want upgrade your system, you should remove this repository from  you repository's list.

Comment: If I remove the full repo http://ftp.stw-bonn.de/ubuntu/ from the repository list, then the upgrade won't be possible. Also, I can't see that specific folder into my sources.list