vscode failed to fetch Forbidden IP repository not signed
i use Studio code as programming IDE.
If i try update the system i get the following error:

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/dists/vscode/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 2620:1ec:bdf::45 443]
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com vscode InRelease' is not signed.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details....

Ideas:
sources.list
Should i add https://packages.microsoft.com the /etc/apt/sources.list file ?
And how?
or do this help?
curl dearmor
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
I have read:
at
https://askubuntu.com/a/1021396/1017209
is commanded
to replaced my "/etc//apt/sources.list" with a default found.
maybe the repo is old? something happens as said here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1021396/1017209
or simply delete(sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list) the list as said here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/515428/1017209
must be changed the download source?
https://askubuntu.com/a/1120871/1017209
Kubuntu 22.04 is my Operating System
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 6.5.0-26-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
Memory: 31,3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
